# Arithmetic overflow error while retriving data from ODS

Tags: sql-server, join

I am keep getting an Arithmetic overflow error while running a query using few joins. I Am copying my query here. Please someone tell me how can I avoid this error moving forward. I've tested everything I could but still nothing is working.

```
Select  COUNT(*)
From    [WVODSFortius].[DimProductCategory] pc
Join    [WVODSFortius].[DimProductCategoryItem] pci 
    On pc.ParentProductCategorySK = pci.ProductCategorySK  -- 36,024
Join    [WVODSFortius].[DimPackage] dp 
    On dp.PackageSK = pci.PackageSK     -- 36,024
join    [WVODSFortius].[DimPackageOption] ppo 
    On dp.PackageSK = ppo.PackageSK   -- 40,797
join    [WVODSFortius].[DimPackageOptionDetail] pod 
    On pod.PackageOptionSK = ppo.PackageOptionSK   -- 238,776
join    [WVODSFortius].[DimProductInventoryDetail] pid 
    On pid.ProductSK = pod.ProductSK  -- 377,715
join    [WVODSFortius].[FactOrders] fc 
    On pid.TenantSK = fc.TenantSK       --- this is where i get Arithmetic overflow error
--Join  [WVODSExigo].[DimCustomers] dc 
    --On fc.CustomerSK = dc.CustomerSK
--Join  [WVODSExigo].[DimLanguages] dl 
    --On dl.LanguageSK = dc.LanguageSK
join    [WVODSFortius].[FactProductTransactionDetail] ptd 
    On ptd.ProductCategorySK = pci.ProductCategorySK
join    [WVODSFortius].[FactProductTransactionDetailExtended] ptde 
    On ptd.ProductTransactionDetailSK = ptde.ProductTransactionDetailSK
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Try `Count_Big()` instead of `Count()`.

Comment: Also, compare the datatypes for `pid.TenantSK` and `fc.TenantSK`, you could have a mismatch there as well.

Comment: Thanks guys. I really appreciate your time. I tried both of your answer and that works :)